# How do I display differently sized images in a row with the same height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

If I have a `<div>` housing multiple `<div><img src="example-link.jpg"/></div>` in it, how do I make them show up on display like the gallery here: https://knds.art/noont

Essentially, I want the images to be resized to the same height of its adjacent image and fill up the entire width of the body.

Things to keep in mind:

- I want the images to display fully (i.e. no `object-fit: cover`)
- I want the images to maintain its aspect ratio when resizing the viewport

I'd list out my attempts but I've been banging my head against a wall for hours now, and at this point I can't even remember what I've tried, and for that I apologize. I've only attempted using CSS to get the desired outcome (i.e. a lot of `display: flex` attempts and wrapping the `div` in additional `div`'s), but I'm wondering if this has to be done with JavaScript, in which case, I'd appreciate it if the solution can be used in React.

Thank you!

EDIT: the images are from a random array, and I'd use the same code for different pages that has different images

Comment: you can use masonry library [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: You can't guarantee to get a nice neat rectangular shape with images in rows and evenly spaced like the one shown in your link with any old set of random aspect ratioed images. That site will have chosen their images with great care to achieve such a neat result.

Comment: @webcoder Oh, nice find! I'll definitely check that out. Though a little bit different from a quick glimpse, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @AHaworth I see. I had an feeling that might be the case as well. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap classes. Like col-lg-6 col-sm-4 something like that. So you can get more documentation on it in W3schools.com or in the bootstrap official website

Comment: Thanks for the response! For that, wouldn't I need to manually assign class values for each individual image wrappers?

EDIT: I realized that I forgot to mention the important part -- I'm trying to build a reusable component, so it'd have to be automated. Sorry about that.

Comment: You would have to assign a bootstrap  class to every image wrapper